# Wrong git diff after chmod on file

Tags: git

initially filemode is 644:

```
$ ls -l mage
-rw-r--r-- 1 gpawlik group 1319 Sep  2 15:45 mage
```

when changing:

```
$ chmod 550 mage
$ ls -l mage 
-r-xr-x--- 1 gpawlik group 1319 Sep  2 15:45 mage
```

good, but then

```
git diff
diff --git a/mage b/mage
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Can anyone explain why it's 755?

I also tried other like 700, 750 even 705 - it's all 755 in new mode in diff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git changes my file permissions upon checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557106/git-changes-my-file-permissions-upon-checkout)

Comment: Git does not *actually* store the file mode.  It stores whether a file is executable or not, using something that looks a lot like an octal file mode (but isn't): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928488/why-git-fast-import-file-modes-are-hardcoded